# Por qué no aparece los -webkit- en mi compilación de SASS

Tags: css, sass

Ayudaaaa. Hice todas las instalaciones para el SASS  y cuando compila el SASS A MI CSS aparece todo menos los webkits o ms flex. No sé que hice mal ni sé como encontrar la respuesta, es primera vez que lo uso.

### Lo que hice:
Instalé sass en la linea de comando npm install -g sass
Instale en VSC Sass y el Live Sass Compiler

Me sale a mi así (primera imagen) y la segunda imagen es como debería ser (del tutorial que estaba haciendo).

Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar en tu pregunta como estas haciendo para compilar tu SASS?

Comment: que herramienta estas usando para compilar esos archivos? según tengo entendido SASS no provee un autopreflxer por defecto por lo tanto debes agregar uno al build pipeline, estas usando algo como gulp, grunt o webpack? o simplemente estas usando el CLI de SASS?

Comment: @Marcos muchas gracias por el consejo al formular preguntas, 
Instalé sass en la linea de comando npm install -g sass 
Instale en VSC Sass y el Live Sass Compiler.

Comment: @MauroAguilar no, no usé nada de eso. Voy a investigarlo de una vez. Gracias!

Comment: el código en su respectivo formato, no en imágenes, por favor.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev oka entendido, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas se llama **autoprefixer** y es básicamente un plugin (o módulo, o programa, como le quieras llamar) que toma el código CSS de entrada y te genera uno modificado agregandole los prefijos que mencionas.

Hay varias formas de usar un autoprefixer pero depende de cómo compilas el código. Por ejemplo si usas algún automatizador de tareas o bundler como gulp, grunt o webpack, cada uno ofrece su forma de implementarlo.

Sin embargo si lo que quieres es simplemente usar un cli para hacer algo rápido y fácil, podrías usar el cli de [postcss](https://postcss.org/):

```
# instalas la herramienta:
npm i -g postcss postcss-cli

# compilas el sass:
sass source.scss output.css --no-source-map

# y le agregas los prefijos con el autoprefixer de postcss:
postcss output.css -u autoprefixer --no-map -o output.css
```

o simplemente instala el plugin [autoprefixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-autoprefixer) de vscode.

Comment: Me queda claro, no sabia bien como buscar ni en google el problema. Muchas gracias Mauro! mañana me pongo con eso. :)